# MFC C++ application is stuck in ProcessShellCommand (CMFCRibbonBar::RecalcLayout)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mfc, freeze

I have a C++ MFC SDI application (MGen), which shows a 10-20 seconds pause between starting and showing GUI on Windows 10. I used MSVS2017 Performance profiler (CPU Usage) to find functions that are taking CPU time in Release build. This pause is inside `ProcessShellCommand` run, specifically in `CMFCRibbonBar::RecalcLayout`, `CMFCRibbonBar::LoadFromResource`, `CDockingManager::EnableAutoHidePanes`.

Pause seems to be removed or reduced when some programs are closed. First I noted that closing Windows Task Manager fixed pause and starting it again returned pause. Then I found out that pause can happen even without Task Manager. Closing Chrome helped to reduce pause to 2-3 seconds.

I also found out that this problem also exists for empty project if it is created by MFC Wizard in MSVS2017.

I tried:

- Rebuild solution - does not help
- All release and debug builds (x86 and x64) have this problem
- Run outside MSVS, run on different PC (Windows 10 too) - does not help
- Restarting Windows seems to fix this problem temporarily (pause disappears).
- I commented out OnApplicationLook() call in CMainFrame::OnCreate().  Pause still exists, because these functions are now called from other places: [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJIO4.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx4TA.png)

Code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/rualark/MGen/blob/master/MGen/MGen.cpp):

```
    BOOL CMGenApp::InitInstance()
    {
        // InitCommonControlsEx() is required on Windows XP if an application
        // manifest specifies use of ComCtl32.dll version 6 or later to enable
        // visual styles.  Otherwise, any window creation will fail.
        INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
        InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
        // Set this to include all the common control classes you want to use
        // in your application.
        InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
        InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

        CWinAppEx::InitInstance();

        // Initialize OLE libraries
        if (!AfxOleInit())
        {
            AfxMessageBox(IDP_OLE_INIT_FAILED);
            return FALSE;
        }

        AfxEnableControlContainer();

        EnableTaskbarInteraction(FALSE);

        // Initialize GDI+
        Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
        Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

        SetRegistryKey(_T("MGen"));
        LoadStdProfileSettings(10);  // Load standard INI file options (including MRU)

        InitContextMenuManager();

        InitKeyboardManager();

        InitTooltipManager();
        CMFCToolTipInfo ttParams;
        ttParams.m_bVislManagerTheme = TRUE;
        theApp.GetTooltipManager()->SetTooltipParams(AFX_TOOLTIP_TYPE_ALL,
            RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCToolTipCtrl), &ttParams);

        // Register the application's document templates.  Document templates
        //  serve as the connection between documents, frame windows and views
        CSingleDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
        pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
            IDR_MAINFRAME,
            RUNTIME_CLASS(CMGenDoc),
            RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame),       // main SDI frame window
            RUNTIME_CLASS(CMGenView));
        AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);

        // Parse command line for standard shell commands, DDE, file open
        CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;

        // Enable DDE Execute open
        EnableShellOpen();

        // Dispatch commands specified on the command line.  Will return FALSE if
        // app was launched with /RegServer, /Register, /Unregserver or /Unregister.
        if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
            return FALSE;

        // The one and only window has been initialized, so show and update it
        m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
        // call DragAcceptFiles only if there's a suffix
        //  In an SDI app, this should occur after ProcessShellCommand
        // Enable drag/drop open
        m_pMainWnd->DragAcceptFiles();
        return TRUE;
    }
```

P.S. I use latest components in both PCs (Intel I7-8700K with 64Gb RAM and Intel I7-4770K with 32 Gb RAM, SSD) and do not experience performance problems. During the pause at application start CPU is used only by the application.

Detailed performance profiler results:
[image: Performance profiler1]
[image: Performance profiler2]

Even more detailed analysis:
[image: Performance profiler3]

Also there are same problems in ExitInstance:
[image: Performance profiler4]

Comment: Well, what's inside of those functions that take so long? Are they perhaps fetching images from remote locations? Doing heavy computations? Since rebooting seems to help temporarily, are other applications also involved? Can you worsen the problem by repeatedly doing some part of this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will try to get those MFC sources and check what happens there. They are standard and I did not override them. This seems strange to me, because starting from ProcessShellCommand there is no my code.

Comment: Please see, I added two screenshots showing what happens inside these functions. They do not fetch remote images (local only). No other applications are involved that I know of. Not sure if I can repetedly do this, because this is part of MFC framework.

Comment: Disable temporary OnApplicationLook(..) in mainframe.cpp and check if this issue persist. You can call it later manally in your program by clicking on View-Application Look.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Tom. I commented out OnApplicationLook() call in CMainFrame::OnCreate().  Pause still exists, because these functions are now called from other places: 
[Image1](https://i.imgur.com/a07nhaC.png)
[Image2](https://i.imgur.com/ofrG8rE.png)

https://github.com/rualark/MGen/commit/d327ae66bb9c5ab7414f8da423192006f05c768c

Comment: Found some information about it: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/136952/mfc-ribbon-slow-on-first-loadshow.html
Also I collected additional info and compared to classic menu here: https://github.com/rualark/MGen/issues/1990

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a known problem in Microsoft. It was fixed with Windows update. So, to fix you need to update Windows 10.